# What's the meaning of "you look like a prune"

Tags: meaning, phrases

In the TV drama 'Boston Legal', Denny Crane says **"you look like a prune"** to his workmate.

What's the meaning of it?

Comment: A prune is a dried plum.  Dessicated, it gets all wrinkly.

Comment: **Desiccated**: one S, two Cs. ;-)

Comment: I disagree that this can be answered by a dictionary. Yes you can look up what a prune is, but that doesn't always explain what folks mean when they are describing a person as similar to a dried fruit. Does it mean wrinkly or is a comment on their color?

Comment: I agree with @ColleenV.  Also: A dictionary won't tell you whether the comparison is typically a compliment or a disparagement.  In some cultures, prunes could be considered handsome fruit - I don't know.  Another example: Saying a woman looks _like a cow_ would usually be an insult in America - I bet there are places in the world where it wouldn't be, and knowing the dictionary definition of "cow" doesn't necessarily reveal that nuance.

Comment: @Victor Bazarov: That's what the dictionaries say, true. But we "ss-ers" are out there, hiding in the shadows.   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dessicated&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdessicated%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine Denny was speaking to someone particularly shrivelled or wrinkly and was being insulting.

The phrase is literal. "You look like a wrinkly purple fruit"

These are prunes; not a particularly pretty thing to be compared to:

[image]

[[Source]](http://images.wisegeek.com/prunes-are-excellent-natural-laxatives.jpg)